# authenticationmanager.getexternallogininfo() returns null always with linkedin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I have used `Oauth2` in my MVC project. We can connect successfully with our app with credentials but after authenticating user return always null in external login call back method.

Checked many solutions but no luck but another login is working fine like Facebook.

For this integration, I have used `Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0` version in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got the solutions after long time.

Add this line in `Startup.cs` file of `ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)` function. Same as per below code.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
      //Add this line at first inside the function.

      System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

      //Other code 

}
```